# How to convert Android.Net.Uri into byte array in C#

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my mobile app using Xamarin.Android, I implemented file attachment feature. In that, I got file content in Android.Net.Uri from

```
protected override async void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Android.Net.Uri attachmentUri = data.Data;
}
```

Now, in order to upload the file as multipart message, I have to convert this uri to byte array. I searched a lot but everything in Java. I need such code in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ContentResolver.OpenInputStream` on the `Android.Net.Uri` to retrieve a stream that you can then use `StreamContent` to convert it to a `ByteArrayContent` object and apply that to your `MultipartFormDataContent`.

#### Example:

```
using (var resolverStream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data))
using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(resolverStream))
using (var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
using (var formDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    formDataContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "file", "DummyFileName");

    // rest of the header setup, PostAsync, etc..

}
```

Comment: Now I have one more requirements. I need to add more than one files into MultipartFormDataContent. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ThamaraiT Use your MultipartFormDataContent instance and call `.Add(...)` for each of your "files" (`ByteArrayContent`).

Comment: Like formDataContent.Add(bytearray1,"file","name1"); formDataContent.Add(bytearray2,"file","name2"); ,  right?

Comment: Yes, that is it

Comment: Okay, I am checking on it. Once done, I will update you. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your multipart message:

```
 var dat = data.Data;
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream filestream;
            try
            {
                filestream = new FileInputStream(new File(dat.Path));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int n = filestream.Read(buffer);
                while (-1 != n)
                {
                    outputstream.Write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
             }
            byte[] filebyte = outputstream.ToByteArray();
```

Comment: I think this is Java code. But I need it in C# code. Please check with @SushiHangover's answer. I implemented based on his answer, it works perfectly.

Comment: Its c#, i tested it myself

Comment: @Tolulope That will work if it is not a `content:` based uri, otherwise you would need to use the ContentResolver.

Comment: @Tolulope Yes. Mine is content uri as told by SushiHangover. Moreover, 'ByteArrayOutputStream' and 'FileInputStream' have reference from 'Java.IO'.

Comment: I get the content uri part, but Java .IO name space is in xamarin Android